# App not compatible on playstore due to android.webkit

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I have published my webview app on playstore but after publishing playstore says it not compatible for everyone and when I asked them why is that so they told me that is because it doesn't have android.webkit. Please let me know what have a missed the code seems fine to me and should be working.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final String URL_NAVER_MAP = "url here";

private WebView webView;
public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    webView.requestFocus();
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        @Override
        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
            super.onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(origin, callback);
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);

        }
        private void displayLocationSettingsRequest(Context context) {
            GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
            googleApiClient.connect();
            final String TAG = "YOUR-TAG-NAME";
            final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;

            LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
            locationRequest.setFastestInterval(10000 / 2);

            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
            builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

            PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
            result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                    final Status status = result.getStatus();
                    switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                            Log.i(TAG, "All location settings are satisfied.");
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                            Log.i(TAG, "Location settings are not satisfied. Show the user a dialog to upgrade location settings ");

                            try {
                                status.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "PendingIntent unable to execute request.");
                            }
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                            Log.i(TAG, "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be fixed here. Dialog not created.");
                            break;
                    }
                }


            });
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                        request.grant(request.getResources());
                    }
                }

            });
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                // Grant permissions for cam
                @Override
                public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onPermissionRequest");
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.d(TAG, request.getOrigin().toString());
                            if(request.getOrigin().toString().equals("file:///")) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "GRANTED");
                                request.grant(request.getResources());
                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "DENIED");
                                request.deny();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }


            });
            try {
                Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
                r.play();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    });

   ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA,Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW, Manifest.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT,Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS}, 0);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW,}, 0);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION}, 0);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS}, 0);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
    webView.loadUrl(URL_NAVER_MAP);

}}
```

Build.gradle => Dependencies

```
dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.webkit:webkit:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
```

}

Manifest Permissions

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.webkit"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have to remove uses feature and upgrade your gradle to latest. Remove androidx webkit implementation too.

`<uses-feature android:name="android.webkit"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove

```
 <uses-feature android:name="android.webkit"/>
```

it is not defined at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element

Comment: Let me try this way, fingers crossed